# Connect Asp.net to Oracle 10.2: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: oracle10g, odp.net

I've go an ASP.net sites that connect to Oracle 11.  That works.
Now I'm trying to have a site that should connect to Oracle 10.2, but I can't find the necessary ODP.Net libraries.
I've downloaded the ODAC components for Oracle 10 from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html), but it crashes when I try to install it (Maybe it's because of the previous files I have for 11g).

When I try to use the Oracle 11 libs, I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I can't find another place to download the necessary libs.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ODAC 10.2 to connect to a 10.2 Database. Any ODAC up to the current 12.1 will work.

What may be happening is:

1) The application has a dependency on ODP.NET 12.1. The error message suggest this. Try installing ODP.NET 12.1.

2) You aren't installing the correct bitness (eg IIS is 64 bit so you need ODAC 64 bit)

3) You aren't doing a proper install and are just copying files and are either missing some of them, or missing a configuration step. Try running the installer (OUI or XCopy) if you are not.

You can get 64 bit ODAC from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Comment: I've downloaded and installed "64-bit ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) for Windows x64" on my machine.  I've added a reference to the new Oracle.DataAccess.dll.  Now get the error: "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
I've tried in 64-bit, x86 and AnyCPU.  When in 64-bit mode the error changes to "Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp' or one of its dependencies..."